# Alguna manera para cambiar dentro de una tabla un OK o NG por imagen o Css? MVC Asp javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, css, mvc

[![Cambiar la salida por imagen o css para mostrar un color verde o rojo

si alguien tiene alguna manera de que el resultado de una base de datos cambie de acuerdo a ello,
se hace una peticion a sql server, se muestra la tabla y deacuerdo al valor hacer un cambio a una imagen  o un estilo css para sea mas facil visual identificar

```html
<div class="row">
           
                <table class="content-table">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr class="">
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(p => Model[0].id)</td>
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(P => Model[0].nombre)</td>
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(P => Model[0].familia)</td>
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(P => Model[0].serie)</td>
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(P => Model[0].fecha)</td>
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(P => Model[0].resultado)</td>
</thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                        <tr class="active-row">
                            <td>@item.id</td>
                            <td>@item.nombre</td>
                            <td>@item.familia</td>
                            <td>@item.serie</td>
                            <td>@item.fecha</td>
                            <td>@item.resultado</td>

                        </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
           
        </div>
```

> [image: introducir el código aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amigo así es como yo lo ocupo espero te de una idea

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FotoRuta))
        {
            <img src="@Url.Content(item.FotoRuta)" alt="image" style="width:30px; height:30px; max-width:100%; height:auto" />
        }
        else
        {                
            <img src="~/Content/Upload/FotosUsuarios/Anonimo.jpg" alt="image" style="width:30px; height:30px; max-width:100%; height:auto" />
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono de maravilla!